# How to do a date format in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I need to understand how to do date formattting in javascript.

i have date as,

```
var date="12/02/1994";// dd/mm/yyy
var date1=new Date(date);
date1.getDate();// this gives me Month which is 02
date1.getMonth();// this gives me date which is 12.
```

How do i get the exact date i have in var date in get date and getmonth function? Please help

Comment: Because `new Date` will treat this date as __Fri Dec 02 1994 00:00:00__

Comment: Timezone will be the local timezone of user

Comment: If you want to play save, you can write a function which strips your string ( or use a plugin ) and use the `new Date(year, month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);` construct - [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple: JavaScript uses `mm/dd/yyyy` data format.

It doesn't support `dd/mm/yyyy` format, so, if you need to parse this format, then you will have to do this manually like this:

```
function parseDdmmyyyy(str)
{
    var spl = str.split('/');
    return new Date(spl[2], spl[1] - 1, spl[0]);
}
```

or you will have to use external libraries like Moment.js.

Comment: _(YYYY-MM-DD)_ is also the preferred JavaScript date format

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `date()` expects date in `mm/dd/yy` and not in `dd/mm/yy`. And `months` start from `0` and not `1`.

```
var from = "12/02/1994".split("/");
var date1 = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
date1.getDate();
date1.getMonth();
```

Comment: Javascript Date objects don't expect any particular format, though they do try to parse strings that are given them in various formats. Only one is specified in the standard and that's not the one in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Date('02/12/1994')`, `new Date('1994-02-12')` or `new Date(1994, 02-1, 12)`, because in js months start from 0 and american date format is used where month goes first

Answer (score 0):

you can use the simple JS file [DateFormat.js](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/compact/date.js) which has some very good example through the URL [mattkruse (Date Funtion)](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/) 
from this JS file you can validate the incoming date is a true format even you can add format date within a several ways.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to know how to format strings so they are consistently parsed by browsers. The short answer, is there is no guarantee that any particular string will be correctly parsed by all browsers in use (or perhaps even most).

So the bottom line is: don't parse strings with the Date constructor, ever. It's largely implementation dependent and even the one format specified in ES5 and ECMAScript 2015 is poorly and inconsistently supported.

How browsers treat a string like "12/02/1994" is entirely implementation dependent, however most will treat it as the peculiar US month/day/year format, i.e. 2 December and *getMonth* will return 11, since months are zero indexed.

So you should always manually parse strings (a library can help, but a simple parsing function is only 2 lines, 3 if validation is required), e.g.

```js
// Parse a date string as d/m/y
// If s is not a valid date, return a Date object with its
// time value set to NaN.
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && b[1] == d.getMonth()? d : new Date(NaN);
}

document.write(parseDMY('12/02/1994'));
```